# JSON schema defining single use of elements from a set

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I using *draft-04* to define JSON schema.
My original problem was something like i wanted to define schema for below structure

```
{
"config1" : [
              { <category-1> : {some Object which i know how to define schema} },
              { <category-2> : {some Object which i know how to define schema} }
            ],
"config2" : {some other structure}
}
```

here category-n is a category defined in n-element set containing categories.
I know a schema defines a *static* data structure hence we can't enumerate on keys (correct?) so as a work around, i need to have config1 as follows

```
"config1" : [
              { "categoryName" : "category-1"
                "categoryPayload" : {some Object which i know how to define schema} },
              { "categoryName" : "category-2"
                "categoryPayload" : {some Object which i know how to define schema} }
            ]
```

for each category definition, i know i can use like ***"enum": ["category-1", "category-1"]*** but the problem is, in the first json i was getting benefit of json recommendation of not using duplicate keys. Each category is unique and i dont want someone to use different categoryPayload for the same category. How can i restrict array elements of config-1 to just have 1 element per category (no duplicate category elements)

## Edit-1

Taking example of my derived approach (using category as value instead of keys), suppose category-1, category-2 and category-3 are allowed categories. hence following json should pass the validation

```
{
  "config-1": [
    {
      "categoryName": "category-1",  //line-1
      "categoryPayload": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "category-2",   //line-2
      "categoryPayload": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key3": "value3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "config-2": "something"
}
```

If a replace line-1 with category-2 (both line-1 and 2 having same values), this should fail the validation. And obviously if i replace category-7 (not part of allowed enum) at line-1, it should also fail the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Is schema for each category never be the same? You can't assert uniqueness of values of object but its uniqueness of schemas.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "config1": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "patternProperties": {
            "\\w+": {
              "oneOf": [
                {"type": "object", "properties": {"a": {}}, "additionalProperties": false},
                {"type": "object", "properties": {"b": {}}, "additionalProperties": false}
              ]
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Update:
This is an alternative way:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "config1": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}, "uniqueItems": true},
          {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "object"}, "uniqueItems": true},
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

This way you can have unique keys and values. And you zip two array in your application.

This is passed:

```
{
  "config1" : [
    ["category-1", "category-2"],
    [{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}]
  ]
}
```

This is failed:

```
{
  "config1" : [
    ["category-1", "category-2"],
    [{"a": 1}, {"a": 1}]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tired for response, i think expectation is not clear. I made edits in my question to reflect that.

Comment: Your structure is not appropriated for what you wanted to accomplish. You want the  `categoryName` to be unique, but that latest structure is not possible (in my knowledge) to write schema for the purpose.

I proposed an alternative data structure so that it's possible to write schema for your purpose.

Comment: In case you didn't know I omitted the enum part, but you can have `"enum": ["category-1", "category-2"] ` along with `{"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}, "uniqueItems": true}` in my second solution.

If your structure looks like `{ "categoryName": "category-1", "categoryPayload": {}}` you cannot validate uniqueness of neither `categoryName` nor `categoryPayload` except BOTH fields' values are the same.

Comment: Actually your structure decouples all the configs from a category. I want to have an entity logically related to a category, thats why i wanted to store category as a key and associated object as its value but that mapping was also not possible to strictly validate and hence i moved to a derived approach.  In your solution, that logical relation is brittle and just based on the index position which is bad design and error prone in my use case :)

Comment: I think every language has zip function, and you can enforce minItems maxItems to have both arrays length identical. But I think first structure and my first solution should work. The `oneOf` is basically XOR.

It's weird choice when you tag category-n to object and expect that object to be unique since tagging means forcing it to be different (allow same category object with diff names)

I would not name it (tagging), and just `{"config1" : [config_obj_1, config_obj_2]}` so you can use `uniqueItems`